# Why ExecutorService is not shutdown after invokeAny returns a result?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, java-threads, callable

As I was experimenting with Future and Callable in Java, I had a result I cannot make sense of with my current understanding. **The below scenario is for demonstration purposes only.**

From my understanding, when a collection of `Callable`s are submitted to an `ExecutorService` via an `invokeAny()` call, `ExecutorService` returns the first result it gets out of them. After the retrieval of the result, I call `executorService.shutDown()` which I expected to shutDown the executorService as it already return a result. However, for the below scenario the program halts. I have also tried calling `executorService.shutDownNow()` but no luck.

I've tried the same example using two methods that only sleeps the their thread for `1000` and `5000` seconds respectively, and after the first one is done sleeping `executorService.shutDown()` worked as expected.

My only guess is that `shutDown()` or `shutDownNow()` cannot interrupt an already executing thread just like `cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning=true)` does.

Could someone please explain what's going on here, am I guessing this correctly?

Here's the example:

```java
public class InvokeAnyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        int N = 50; // If I set N = 10, program exits successfully.

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Callable<Long> naiveFibonacci = () -> {
            log("Naive Fibonacci");
            long result = fibonacciNaive(N);
            log("Naive Fibonacci Finished");
            return result;
        };

        Callable<Long> optimizedFibonacci = () -> {
            log("Optimized Fibonacci");
            long[] cache = new long[1000];
            Arrays.fill(cache, -1);
            long result = fibonacciOptimized(N, cache);
            log("Optimized Fibonacci Finished");
            return result;
        };

        Long result = executorService.invokeAny(Arrays.asList(naiveFibonacci, optimizedFibonacci), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        log(String.valueOf(result));

        executorService.shutdown();
//        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static long fibonacciNaive(int n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;

        return fibonacciNaive(n - 1) + fibonacciNaive(n - 2);
    }

    private static long fibonacciOptimized(int n, long[] cache) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
        if (cache[n] != -1) return cache[n];

        long result = fibonacciOptimized(n - 1, cache) + fibonacciOptimized(n - 2, cache);
        cache[n] = result;

        return result;
    }

    private static void log(String message) {
        String prefix = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(String.format("In Thread (%s) : %s", prefix, message));
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
In Thread (pool-1-thread-2) : Optimized Fibonacci
In Thread (pool-1-thread-1) : Naive Fibonacci
In Thread (pool-1-thread-2) : Optimized Fibonacci Finished
In Thread (main) : 12586269025
--- PROGRAM HALTS
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the program halts"? In any case, given none of your tasks are interruptible, they will continue running until they are done. The cancellation performed by `invokeAny` will not have any effect unless it performs a blocking operation or if it actively checks `Thread.interrupted()` (or does anything else that allows for interruption).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, with "the program halts" I was trying to say "executor service cannot be shutdown although I call `shutDownNow()` at the end". That's a good point for me to investigate further, I need to look for what makes a task _interruptable_.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, actually I was not expecting `invokeAny()` to shutdown, I was expecting after I ran `invokeAny()` I would be able to run `executorService.shutDown()` and the program would end successfully - but it does not end. I was expecting this because I understood `invokeAny()` returns the first result so it was OK to cancel any remaining task and shut down the executor by calling `shutDown()` on it.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Rotteveel wrote in his comment:

The `naiveFibonacci` task is not interruptible. It does not call any methods that check the interrupted state of the thread nor does `fibonacciNaive()` method itself check the interrupted state of the thread.

If you want to make `fibonacciNaive()` method interruptible you could change it to:

```
private static long fibonacciNaive(int n) throws InterruptedException {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;

    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        log("interrupt detected");
        throw new InterruptedException();
    }

    return fibonacciNaive(n - 1) + fibonacciNaive(n - 2);
}
```

And with that change the `naiveFibonacci` task will be stopped as soon as `optimizedFibonacci` produces a result.

Changed: as Holger commented, using `Thread.interrupted()` is preferable over `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` since the code in the `if` statement is going the handle the interruption.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense! I was missing the part that "not everything is interruptable". And thank you for showing me how to make it interruptable.